# Understanding how the german tax system works

Tags: taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, germany

I hope that you can help me understand how the German tax system works.

I recently found a job in Berlin with a yearly gross salary of 68000. I am married (we are both Spanish) but my husband is still working in the UK with a yearly gross salary of 47000 pounds.

My questions are:

1. In which tax classes do we belong?
2. If he moves to Berlin, registers here and we live together with him being unemployed will we pay less for taxes?  Which case (1st or 2nd) is the most favourable for us in order to pay less taxes?

Comment: Are you asking whether, from a tax perspective, it would be better for him to live and work in the UK or to be unemployed and living with you?  Are those choices case 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

1. Tax class is 1 if the spouse isn't even in the country.
2. You will pay far less in taxes if you have an unemployed spouse living with you. You'll also have far less money.